# VueJs DropZone - How to resize preloaded images to fit the thumbnail size

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, dropzone.js

First of all, I am using Vue DropZone to upload photos. I currently have a preloaded image in the dropzone. I manage to achieve this by referencing the vueDropZone component and calling the manuallyAddFile(file, url) method. However, I have trouble resizing the preloaded image to fit the thumbnail box, which has a size of 160 x 160 px. I've tried to apply the following CSS class, but it does not work

```
.dz-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Just to give a clearer picture, I will provide my code and a few screenshots of what I want to achieve.

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <vue-dropzone id="dropzone" ref="myVueDropzone" :options="dropOptions" :useCustomSlot="true">
      <div class="dropzone-custom-content">
        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-3x"></i>
        <h4 class="dropzone-custom-title mb-0 mt-3">Drag & Drop</h4>
      </div>
    </vue-dropzone>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vueDropzone from "vue2-dropzone";

export default {
  components: {
    vueDropzone
  },
  data() {
    return {
      /* This is similar to configuration options in dropzone.js */
      dropOptions: {
        url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        thumbnailWidth: 160,
        thumbnailHeight: 160
      }
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    var file = {
      // Specify the file size and type of file
      size: 160,
      type: "image/jpeg"
    };
    var url = require("../assets/child.jpeg");
    this.$refs.myVueDropzone.manuallyAddFile(file, url);
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

This is the size of the preloaded photo
[image]

This the size of the preloaded photo as compared to the user uploaded photo.
Basically, I want the preloaded photo to match the user uploaded photo, which has a size of 160 x 160 px
[image]